# Computing Cochain complex using matrices

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm currently studying for a (timed) qualifying exam which covers cohomology and as such it would be helpful to know time-saving methods of computation. I've come across computations of cohomology where the chain complex maps and cochain complex maps are represented by matrices. For example in problem 3.1.6 in these homework solutions: http://math.stanford.edu/~ralph/math215c/solution1.pdf

I really like the idea of avoiding $\operatorname{Hom}(-,G)$ calculations and doing linear algebra instead, but as the example of this method I found is just someone's homework, I'm unsure of it's validity.

For example, let's compute the cohomology groups of the Klein Bottle with $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients using the CW structure found on page 102 in Hatcher: [image: CW Structure]

First we write down the Chain complex: $$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}^2 \xrightarrow{\partial_2} \mathbb{Z}^3 \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 $$
where $\partial_2$ is given by the matrix $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{array} \right)$ because the boundary map is $U \mapsto a + b -c$ and $L \mapsto a - b + c$.

Now we dualize to get the cochain complex:
$$0 \leftarrow \mathbb{Z}^2 \xleftarrow{\delta_2} \mathbb{Z}^3 \xleftarrow{0} \mathbb{Z} \leftarrow 0 $$
where $\delta_2$ is given by the transposed matrix $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & -1\\
1 & -1 & 1
\end{array} \right)$.

Now computing the cohomology groups we immediately see that $H^0(K)=H^1(K)=\mathbb{Z}$. I know that we should get $H^2(K)=\mathbb{Z}_2$, so I think the image of $\delta_2$ should be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times 2\mathbb{Z}$ but I'm having trouble seeing this.

So, in summary my questions are

1. Is this a valid method of computing cochain complexes? Is it only valid under certain conditions?

   2. If it is, how do I see what the image of $\delta_2$ is?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The image is the space spaned by the columns, in your case 
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$ and its easy to see that this is the same as

$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ now you just nee to see that the quotient by this space is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

In particular $$\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}\equiv\begin{pmatrix}a-b\\0\end{pmatrix}\mod \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$$